# JMeter: Call java class file in JSR223 Sampler

Tags: class, groovy, jmeter

I used

```
new Packages.ml.bh.security.CUploader();
```

in BSF Sampler. Now I'm using JSR223 Sampler with groovy and there's error

> Response message: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script2.groovy: 10: unable to resolve class
>   Packages.ml.bh.security.CUploader

How can I call a method inside a jar file in JSR233 Sampler?

Comment: did you put the jar containing this class in the classpath? the default location is `jmeterhome/lib`

Comment: Yep, I did. Everything is fine with BSF sampler. The problem occurs when I use JSR233 sampler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Packages. from your import if your full class name is:

- ml.bh.security.CUploader